# Like в DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

Поддерживает ли `DataTable` фильтрацию по `LIKE` с использованием `[]`?

Например, `dt.Select("Column LIKE '%[123]%'")`

Вроде бы, оператор `LIKE` есть, но ловлю ругань при использовании такого синтаксиса.

Comment: а можно больше кода, чтоб более вникнуть в суть проблемы?

Comment: добавил чуть больше.

Comment: попробуйте без одинарных скобок: dt.Select("Column LIKE %[123]%")

Comment: очень похожая проблема: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589283/how-to-get-like-clause-to-work-in-ado-net-and-sql-server

Comment: @Yaroslav не совсем. Там запрос напрямую к SQL.

Comment: можно еще попробовать через параметры задать

private Dictionary QuerySearchResultsParameters
        {
            get
            {
                Dictionary parameters = new Dictionary();
                parameters.Add("param1", tbSearchTerm.Text);
                return parameters;
            }
        }

Comment: Квадратные скобки в фильтрах DataTable, судя по всему, используются только для экранирования. С их помощью нельзя указать диапазон или список символов..[Expression Syntax](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=netframework-4.7.2#expression-syntax)